# Why does this js slideshow work on one install and not the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, expressionengine

I am building a new site. I have the first page in dev here: http://dev.rouviere.com/yoga/ and everything is working correctly, including the image slideshow.

However, on this [install](http://yogahealthfoundation.com/), which is running on Expression Engine, the slideshow does not work and I get the following error in Chrome Inspector:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I need another pair of eyes to help me see what I am missing here. All the resources are loading, including the image for the four button/dots, but there is something wrong that is causing the script to fail and the slideshow not work.

HTML

```
<div class="window">
    <div class="image_reel">
        <a href="#"><img src="/images/slideshow-1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="/images/slideshow-1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="/images/slideshow-1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="/images/slideshow-1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
</div><!-- end window -->
```

The Script in question:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Set Default State of each portfolio piece
    $(".paging").show();
    $(".paging a:first").addClass("active");

    //Get size of images, how many there are, then determin the size of the image reel.
    var imageWidth = $(".window").width();
    var imageSum = $(".image_reel img").size();
    var imageReelWidth = imageWidth * imageSum;

    //Adjust the image reel to its new size
    $(".image_reel").css({'width' : imageReelWidth});

    //Paging + Slider Function
    rotate = function(){    
        var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1; //Get number of times to slide
        var image_reelPosition = triggerID * imageWidth; //Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide

        $(".paging a").removeClass('active'); //Remove all active class
        $active.addClass('active'); //Add active class (the $active is declared in the rotateSwitch function)

        //Slider Animation
        $(".image_reel").animate({ 
            left: -image_reelPosition
        }, 500 );

    }; 

    //Rotation + Timing Event
    rotateSwitch = function(){      
        play = setInterval(function(){ //Set timer - this will repeat itself every 3 seconds
            $active = $('.paging a.active').next();
            if ( $active.length === 0) { //If paging reaches the end...
                $active = $('.paging a:first'); //go back to first
            }
            rotate(); //Trigger the paging and slider function
        }, 10000); //Timer speed in milliseconds (3 seconds)
    };

    rotateSwitch(); //Run function on launch

    //On Hover
    $(".image_reel a").hover(function() {
        clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
    }, function() {
        rotateSwitch(); //Resume rotation
    }); 

    //On Click
    $(".paging a").click(function() {   
        $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
        //Reset Timer
        clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
        rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
        rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation
        return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
    }); 
});
```

Comment: The dropmenu plugin misuses `jQuery.noConflict();` which leaves `$` undefined. The functioning site doesn't load the plugin so it doesn't get to interfere. The quick fix is therefore to remove the `jQuery.noConflict();` line from the start of jquery.dropmenu.js.

Comment: Hi Juhana, excellent response. Promote your comment to an answer and I will give you credit for the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's doing this because instead of pulling your JS file (s) it's pulling your site index page. The first character of your index page is "<"

Sounds like you have htaccess configured to drop "index.php" using include. Be sure that your js directory is included in the ones set up not to reroute.